# Apache Virtual Host with path

Tags: apache, path, dns, virtual, host

I am deploying a Rails app with Phusion passenger and Apache HTTPD, to do that I have to create a virtual host in Apache to associate the root of my app. And this process is successful, effectively my app is running, but my problem is that I have to do this run in a path of my domain, such as "mydomain.com/railsapp".
I tried this configurations and all failed.**

## Configuration 1

```
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
ServerName mydomain.com/railsapp

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /app

DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/app/public
<Directory /var/www/rails/app/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
     #Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

## Configuration 2

```
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerPath /railsappp

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /app

DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/app/public
<Directory /var/www/rails/app/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
     #Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

## Configuration 3

```
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com/railsappp

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /app

DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/app/public
<Directory /var/www/rails/app/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
     #Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Does Anyone have idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use ServerName as my domain.com     and make use of ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directive to redirect /railsapp to desired location....      Read more about reverse proxy..